# Intellij AutoComplete import could not find java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, autocomplete, packages, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij version.2013.3.4 (built on January 31, 2017) on OSX.

The problem is when I using `HashMap`, it never find `java.util.HashMap`.
Is this only happens to me ? Since I am using `HashMap` frequently, it is so uncomfortable.

It recommends `org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap`, which I do not need at all.

I want to know how to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: By default, under a new Java project it works as intended. Are you using a different JDK or something?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Thanks. It just suddenly works well.